# Java Date of Birth Input and Output

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use Scanner method to let me input a date of birth in this format - mm/dd/yy
and the output that I'd like to get would be something like this.

```
Input - 02/06/12
Output - February 6, 2012
```

I'm also trying to limit the value for day(dd) and make sure it doesn't go past 32, and the value for year(yy) to not exceed 2022. I assume I save the input as a String, however I'm not sure how to separate them and have a condition where I can assign certain String values to each month.

Comment: Please add your current code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Parse as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object. Automatically localize to generate output text.

```
LocalDate
.parse( 
    "02/06/12" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uu" )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM )
    .withLocale( Locale.US ) 
)
```

To handle faulty input, trap for `DateTimeParseException`.

To constrain the year, interrogate for the year using `LocalDate#getYear`. Or, build a custom [Jakarta Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) constraint.

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code to your above problem statement as given below. Please add logic for date accordingly as I am assuming that you will be submitting the date in `YYYY` format.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Date:");
    String date = scanner.nextLine();  // Read user input
    System.out.println("Submitted Date is: " + date);  // Output user input
    String arr[] = date.split("/");
    System.out.println("Output --> " + getMonth(arr[0]) + " " + getDate(arr[1]) + ", " + arr[2]);
  }

  public static String getMonth(String month) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(month) > 12) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Month");
    }
    switch (month) {
      case "01":
        return "January";
      case "02":
        return "February";
      case "03":
        return "March";
      case "04":
        return "April";
      case "05":
        return "May";
      case "06":
        return "June";
      case "07":
        return "July";
      case "08":
        return "August";
      case "09":
        return "September";
      case "10":
        return "October";
      case "11":
        return "November";
      case "12":
        return "December";
      default:
        return "Invalid Month";
    }
  }

  public static String getDate(String date) {
    if (date.startsWith("0")) {
      return String.valueOf(date.charAt(1));
    }
    if (Integer.parseInt(date) > 31) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Date");
    }
    return date;
  }
```

Comment: Java offers date-time classes for this work. No need to write all this parsing and generating code yourself.

Comment: Got it, Thankyou @BasilBourque for this valuable information.